# Adding an image to google maps as a background (transparent)

Tags: google-maps

I am developing an app for mobile platforms, for now just for ios and using google maps. Well I created a polygon for Switzerland like that

[image]

As you see the color is red, but i would like to use switzerland's flag instead of red color. Google provide a link that you can add an image onto the map but its not like a map, it should be transparent, i found a sample

[image]

http://www.maphill.com/switzerland/simple-maps/flag-map/
as you see its a flag (maybe not an image but has two colors)

So how can i do the same thing in google maps.

This code is about filling map as red color

```
public override MKOverlayRenderer OverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
   if (overlay is MKPolygon)
   {
    var polygonOverlay = overlay as MKPolygon;
    var polygonView = new MKPolygonRenderer(polygonOverlay);
    polygonView.FillColor = UIColor.FromRGB(180, 16, 27);
    polygonView.Alpha = 0.4f;
    polygonView.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
    polygonView.LineWidth = 10;
    return polygonView;

  }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code about how you make the Switzerland area red? Do you use MKMapRect to approach that?

Comment: @ztan, you can check here http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36280/country-polygons-cannot-be-added-onto-the-map-in-real-device-iphone

Comment: Seems you have resolve your problem  by changing the language.

Comment: @ztan, yes but it was another problem, i couldnt draw the map for switzerland in iphone because of language issue. But here i asked how can i put a background for switzerland (like  figure 2)